# Understanding `sed` command

Tags: sed

Suppose that a file `names` contains a list of names in the form: "firstname lastname", one per line. These names are unsorted, and you would like them sorted by lastname. However, the format of names on each line should remain the same. Which **ONE** of the following commands will **NOT** output an appropriately sorted list of names to the console?

> `[ ]cut -f 2 -d " " names | paste names - | sort -k 3 | cut -f 1`
>
> `[x]sort -k 2 names`   ← Wrong answer
>
> `[ ]sed 's/\(\w*\) \(\w*\)/\2 \1 \2/' names | sort | cut -f 2-3 -d " "`
>
> `[ ]cut -f 2 -d " " names | sort`
>
> `[ ]cut -f 2 -d " " names | paste - names | sort | cut -f 2`

What I don't get is how the following produces the requested output:

```
sed 's/\(\w*\) \(\w*\)/\2 \1 \2/' names | sort | cut -f 2-3 -d " "
```

I.E. sorts the names alphabetically by last name but preserving the format of "firstname lastname".  How does the `\w` followed by a `*` work? I thought a filename preceded by a space had to follow.  How does `\w` even apply here?

Comment: @DopeGhoti On the contrary, the first option does work. What doesn't work is the forth option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Note that the below only applies to GNU `sed`; BSD `sed` will behave differently.</sub>

Okay, let's take it step by step, using this for the contents of `names`:

```
Alice Zylanzy
Zepher Applecart
Michael Copperside
```

We'll take the command and go through it piece by piece to see how it works:

```
$ sed 's/\(\w*\) \(\w*\)/\2 \1 \2/' names
Zylanzy Alice Zylanzy
Applecart Zepher Applecart
Copperside Michael Copperside
```

So the `sed` command slaps a duplicated surname at the front of the line.  We then do a simple `sort`:

```
$ sed 's/\(\w*\) \(\w*\)/\2 \1 \2/' names | sort
Applecart Zepher Applecart
Copperside Michael Copperside
Zylanzy Alice Zylanzy
```

Cool, now they're sorted by surname.  Now we use `cut` to get rid of the prefix we used:

```
$ sed 's/\(\w*\) \(\w*\)/\2 \1 \2/' names | sort | cut -f 2-3 -d " "
Zepher Applecart
Michael Copperside
Alice Zylanzy
```

..and Bob's your uncle, as they say.

Getting into the weeds of *how* that `sed` command works:  `\w` is a magic incantation which means "word character", which is shorthand for `/[0-9A-Za-z_]/`.  `\w*` simply means zero or more "word characters", which is how the names are grouped.  Presuming none of the names have underscores or numerals in them, it could be rewritten as:

```
sed 's/\([A-Za-z]*\) \([A-Za-z]*\)/\2 \1 \2/' names
```

To break apart the entire `sed` command piece by piece:

The sed command `s` is a "search and replace" or "substitute" command.  The expression between the first and second `/`s is replaced with what is between the second and third `/`s.

So we are replacing this:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
  )                        end of \1
                           ' '
  (                        group and capture to \2:
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
  )                        end of \2
```

With this:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \2                       what was matched by capture \2
                           ' '
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
                           ' '
  \2                       what was matched by capture \2
```

Comment: Oh okay, when I looked up what \w meant it said "write to filename", I don't think I say an explanation for "word character" in the man page.  I assume that \2 and \1 just mean the first and second argument in the preceding part of sed?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user284179 First and second capture group the parenthesis make a capture group

Comment: I have expanded further upon on the `sed` command and how it works; I hope that is helpful in your understanding.